# SQL Server switch data to display something else

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out I can change the data on the fly.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT [EmployeeTC_No] AS "Employee TC#"
      ,[pye_nlast] AS "Name Last"
      ,[pye_nfirst] AS "Name First"
      ,[Dept] AS "Department"
      ,[pye_status] AS "Active"
      ,[HireDate] AS "Hire Date"
      ,[SeparationDate] AS "Separation Date"
  FROM [testing].[dbo].[testing]
```

In the column of pye_status the data comes in as "A" or "T" and I want it to be "1" or "0".

I have tried to add a case statement trying to do some kind of switch but nothing appears to even get me close.

Comment: A simple case statement should work, what did your case statement look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE/WHEN should do the trick:

```
,CASE WHEN [pye_status] = 'A' THEN 1 
WHEN [pye_status] = 'T' THEN 0 
ELSE NULL END AS "Active"
```

Or a simple case/when will work too:

```
, CASE [pye_status]
WHEN 'A' THEN 1 
WHEN 'T' THEN 0
ELSE NULL END AS "Active"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** expression or **[`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function as

```
CASE WHEN [pye_status] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Active]
```

OR

```
IIF([pye_status] = 'A', 1, 0) AS [Active]
```